# Graphical transformation

Tags: analytic-geometry

I have a burning question to ask regarding graphical transformation:

Suppose I have a function $f(x)$

I want to find $f(ax+b)$ for non zero $a,b$.

There are two approaches that I can go:

First: $f(x)\mapsto f(x+\frac{b}{a})\mapsto f(ax+b)$

Second: $f(x)\mapsto f(ax)\mapsto f(ax+b)$

However, when I start to plot the graphical transformation from $\sin(x)$ to $\sin(2x+\pi)$, the first approach will get me a wrong answer. (I will obtain $\cos(2x)$ instead of $\sin(2x)$)

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: It would help if you showed us the steps you took, that way, we can find out what went wrong...

Comment: Sure. $\sin(x)\mapsto \sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2})=\cos(x)\mapsto\cos(2x)$

Comment: I see now, I'm writing up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you made, basically, was knowing too much and being too eager.

When applying the first approach, you did:

$$\sin(x)\mapsto \sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2})=\cos(x)\mapsto\cos(2x)$$

while you *should* do this:

$$\sin(x) \mapsto \sin(x+\frac\pi2)\mapsto \sin(2x+\pi)$$

Your mistake was thinking that just because, for a pair $x,y$ (in your *particular* case, $y$ was equal to $x+\pi/2$) you have $\sin(y) = \cos(x)$, you **cannot** assume that you also have $\sin(2y) = \cos(2x)$, which is where you made your mistake. You assumed (implicitly) that that is the case, by saying

> It's no differetnt to multiply the argument of $\sin(y)$ by $2$ as it is to multiply the argument of $\cos(x)$ by $2$.

Comment: Can you be more specific in the explanation? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Novice Which part is unclear? The point is that you replaced $\sin(y(x))$ with $\cos(x)$, which is correct, but then you also said that $\sin(2\cdot y(x)) = \cos(2\cdot x)$, which is *not* true.

Comment: Is it something along the line that when $x\mapsto x+\frac{\pi}{2}$, the $x$ axis is being changed to $x+\frac{\pi}{2}$ axis. In this case, when we include the scaling, the scaling is done along the $x+\frac{\pi}{2}$ axis.

Comment: @Novice I have no idea what you tried to tell me with that last comment.

Comment: Oh I see it. $2\times y(x)\neq 2\times x$.

Comment: @Novice Actually, $2\cdot y(x) \neq y(2\cdot x)$.

Comment: Your $y(x)$ refers to $x+\frac{\pi}{2}$? Indeed, if that is the case, then $2\cdot y(x)\neq y(2\cdot x)$

Comment: @Novice Precisely! That's why even though you have $\sin(x+\pi/2)=\cos(x)$, you do not have $\sin(2x+\pi)=\cos(2x)$.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about the responses above and a chat with some of my seniors, here is something that I will like to make:

$f(x)\mapsto f(ax):=g(x)\mapsto g(x+\frac{b}{a})=f(ax+b)---(1)$
$f(x)\mapsto f(x+b):=h(x)\mapsto h(ax)=f(ax+b)---(2)$

For the case of $\sin(x)\mapsto \sin(2x+\pi)$,

Using method $(1)$:
$\sin(x)\mapsto \sin(2x):=g(x)\mapsto g(x+\frac{\pi}{2})=\sin(2x+\pi)$

Using method $(2)$:
$\sin(x)\mapsto \sin(x+\pi):=h(x)\mapsto h(2x)=\sin(2x+\pi)$

Method $(1)$ involves a scaling along $x$ axis, followed by a phase change of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Method $(1)$ involves a phase change of $\pi$, followed by a scaling along $x$ axis.

The question I posed earlier, especially at 
$$f(x)\mapsto f(x+\frac{b}{a})\mapsto f(ax+b)$$ treats $x+\frac{b}{a}$ as a whole entity.

I believe if we change the $x$ axis to $x+\frac{b}{a}$ axis, then we can do the have the scaling of factor $a$ to make it $$f[a(x+\frac{b}{a})]=f(ax+b)$$ I don't just simply replace $x$ by $ax$, which otherwise I will get $f(ax+\frac{b}{a})$.